# JIRA REST API JQL query issue with maxResults

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

JIRA's REST API search doesn't honor `maxResults` parameter.

`curl -o lambrusco.txt -k -D- -u admin:admin -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.domain.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=blackpearl&startAt=0&maxResults=4`

No matter what `maxResults` is, it always returns `50` results.

Output:
`{"expand":"schema,names","startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":61,"issues":[{"expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,transitions,renderedFields","id":"15588","self": ...}`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your request looks fine. Here is example on official Atlassian JIRA, which works fine:

`curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=tlay&startAt=1&maxResults=1"  | jq -r '.maxResults'`

Comment: With curl it never gave the desired results, however when I used Php curl to fetch the data it just worked fine.

Comment: This worked without auth?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that it's related to [REST API Bug](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRACLOUD-67006)!

Comment: Weird enough, I got it working with Php curl, maxResults=x will return x results. I really wonder what's wrong with curl requests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the request when using curl as shown by @grundic, otherwise the shell will interpred the ampersand. And note that the API is case sensitive.